# Azure Geo-replication a good fit to reduce downtime during updates

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We currently have an Azure SQL database that supports a web application. It is read only from a user perspective. The problem is we have to drop the tables and reload them with new data each hour, this makes the application unavailable for 5 minutes each hour which is unacceptable.

Reading the information for Azure active geo-replication seems a little vague. I thought I might be able to use active geo-replication to fail over to a secondary database and take the primary offline to do the update and then when the update is complete switch back to the original primary to allow the secondary to auto-sync. However, it is not clear from what I have read about active geo-replication if that scenario is possible.

Could someone provide some help on this problem or direct me toward another possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try to Azure Data Factory since it allows you to append data to a destination table or invoke a stored procedure with custom logic during copy when SQL Server/SQL Azure is used as a "sink". You can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-powershell).

Azure Data Factory allows you to incrementally load data (delta) after an initial full data load by using a watermark column that has the last updated time stamp or an incrementing key. The delta loading solution loads the changed data between an old watermark and a new watermark. You can learn more how to do that with Azure Data Factory on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) article.

Comment: Our problem is that we need to truncate the tables and load the new data. While that is happening the database is no longer available for use. The update takes approximately 5 minutes and happens every hour.

Comment: Instead of having to truncate and reload, have you considered punt databases in sync with SQL Data Sync? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

Answer (score 0):

If the setup takes 5 mins, and the the data is read only, then I would make a new empty DB in every hour, using some C# code or PowerShell script, and run the data import on this new empty DB, and once it is done, I'd change the connection string in the running production application to point to the new updated version of the DB, and then drop the old DB. This way you won't have any downtime, because till the import is running, the application will connect to the old DB, and when the import is done, it will connect to the new DB.